# Entity Framework remove N:M relation by ids

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have a Simple table like this:

> User(Id, FirstName, ...) <===> Role(Id, Title, ...)

witch have N:M relation

what i want to do is to remove the relation in between them by having there Ids, so my method should be like this :

```
public void UnlinkUsersFromRoles(int[] roleIds, int[] userIds)
{
    var myContext = new DefaultContext();
    // ?? <= how to break the relation without loading unnecessary columns
}
```

Comment: not just a "simple [pair of] table[s]" if many-to-many ... there must be a join table between.

Comment: yes there is a table between them, but EF builds it behind the scenes and i dont know how to access it in my datacontext.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this:

```
var rolesToRemove = myContext.Roles.Where(r=> roleIds.Contains(r.Id)).ToArray();
foreach(var user in myContext.Users.Where(u=> userIds.Contains(u.Id)){
   forearch(var var role in rolesToRemove) {
       user.Roles.Remove(role);
   } 
}
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

When you say:

> how to break the relation without loading unnecessary columns

You mean, the above code doesn't fullfill you requeriment?

EDIT:

If you have a explicity relationship class like UserInRoles, you should use John Castleman Answer, or just create one, map the ForeignKeys and use his solution.

Comment: Yes, in my case the both tables have more than 20+ columns and some of them are byte[] . so loading such data to just removing a link is not a good idea and has an bad performance.

Comment: Wouldn't this actually remove the `Role` rows from the database, not just drop the relations between the two table rows?

Comment: @EhsanErshadi its depends on his model, but i think the relationship class like UserInRoles isn't explicity declared, so entity framework create the table behind the scenes and in this case, i think that no, it wont remove all roles, just the relationship.

Comment: 20+ columns for a `Role` table??? That doesn't sound good @EhsanErshadi. I think in that case the join class is indeed the best option.

Comment: @Gert Arnold  this is only an sample, in my case the tables are different from the ones in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If this is many-to-many relationship, there must be a join table in between: for these tables `User` and `Role`, let's say it's called `UserRole`, and is a simple join table (i.e., no other columns on that table, other than the FK ids to the other two tables):

```
public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

With an explicitly defined join table such as this, `UnlinkUsersFromRoles` could be defined as follows:

```
public void UnlinkUsersFromRoles(int[] roleIds, int[] userIds)
{
    using (var context = new DefaultContext())
    {
        foreach (var ur in context.UserRoles
                                  .Where(u => userIds.Contains(u.UserId))
                                  .Where(r => roleIds.Contains(r.RoleId))
                                  .ToArray())
        {
            context.UserRoles.Remove(ur);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

You're certainly going to wind up loading all the `UserRole` rows to be removed in when you call `ToArray`, but this is certainly better than loading in all the related `User` and `Role` rows.

Comment: thanks @John Castleman, i got the idea, but how do i have to get the UserRoles table in my datacontext. i don't have such table and i thing EF is dealing with it in behind of scenes.